# Why are two kernels (uImage and vmlinux) necessary for u-boot?

Tags: kernel, boot, u-boot

I understand that u-boot requires `uImage` (a kernel image with extra headers) and a filesystem (which includes a kernel titled `vmlinux` in the `/boot` folder. Why is two kernels necessary?

Comment: It doesn't, why do you think it does?

Comment: Because my flash chip requires a `uImage` binary and a filesystem with `vmlinux` binary present. This seems like two kernels to me? Am i misunderstanding something about the boot process?

Comment: What processor architecture are you using?

Comment: @sawdust powerpc

Comment: Why do you think your filesystem requires a vmlinux binary present?  It quite likely does not.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't - They're different formats of the same files.
`vmlinux` is the uncompressed kernel binary whereas `uImage` is the kernel with U-Boot header (a la FIT image).
If you are booting from U-Boot you should only require the uImage file.